# JQuery Mobile adding ui-corner-bottom to first list item

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have been trying out JQuery Mobile with some success. The problem i'm now having is the first line of my list has added 'ui-corner-bottom' to the class, creating first list item to have corners on the bottom. Any help or ideas on this more than welcome.

Code attached below:
http://pastie.textmate.org/2230870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('ul li:first').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
```

Comment: it would work, but a bit of a workaround isn't it rather than getting to the route, of where my code is wrong. Also where would this sit? if i place just after '$("#sect_"+sectionid+"").listview();' it only seems to do the first ul list

Comment: So jQuery must be adding the class to what it thinks is the last child, then you append another <li> to the list and it doesn't know to change the classes. So if the order of the list isn't an issue then you get try prepending the new <li>